# How to load a table from a text file in python?

Tags: python

I have 16 text files, each file contains one table, each table looks like this:

```
Byte[1]=[1234,3455,7565,2345]
```

I want to load each table in order to use it, files differs in their name just in the number of byte.I use those lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
 test=[]
 for b in range(16):
    path= "/local/home/Point_Of_Interest_For_Byte_'+str(b)+'.txt"
    test=np.load(path)
    print(test)
```

As a result, I want to have `test=[1234,3455,7565,2345]`,  but It gives me this error:

```
"Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file '/local/home/Point_Of_Interest_For_Byte_0.txt' as a pickle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this : (untested)

```
np.save(path, test)
```

And then :

```
test=np.load(path)
```

EDIT :

Another solution could be loading the file into a string first : (untested)

```
with f as file.open(path):
  foo = f.readlines()
test = np.load(foo)
```

EDIT:

This solution gives the nearest answer but not the correct one:

```
with f as file.open(path):
      foo = f.readlines()
      print(foo)
```

It gives this solution:

```
['Byte[0] =[3836, 3830, 3841, 3824, 3846]\n']
['Byte[1] =[4713, 4718, 4723, 4707, 4699]\n']
['Byte[2] =[1586, 1591, 1580, 1596, 1601]\n']
```

But what is needed is just: `test= [3836, 3830, 3841, 3824, 3846]`

Comment: But I can't load a text file

Comment: Did you call the `np.save(path, test)` function ?

Comment: yess i have created my file by that way in another script

Comment: It gives me this error:  File "Reading_Data.py", line 7, in <module>
    test=[np.load(lines)]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 402, in load
    magic = fid.read(N)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Sure you can !!

Comment: Thank you, could you take a look please

Comment: @RyanU, instead of trying anything aphazardly and adding untested and non working code edit after edit, you may want to first try your "solutions" and only post when you get something that answers the question ?

Comment: @RyanU  I need your help

Answer (score 0):

What your files contain is neither valid python nor a pickled object nor json nor csv nor any other standard format I can think of, so the simple solution is probably to parse them by yourself instead of expecting "something" to magically guess what it should do with them.

Hopefully given your file format description the parsing should be quite simple : get the single text line, split it on the "=" sign, retrieve the right part (which is valid python syntax for a list) and pass it to `ast.literal_eval()`, which should be mostly safe here:

```
import ast

def read_list(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        content = f.read()
    try:
        raw_data = content.strip().split("=", 1)[1]
    except IndexError as e:
        raise ValueError("file {} does'nt seem valid (error : {})".format(path, e))
    try:
        data = ast.literal_eval(raw_data)
    except SyntaxError as e:
        raise ValueError("file {} does'nt seem valid (error: {})".format(path), e)
    return data



for b in range(16):
    path = "/local/home/Point_Of_Interest_For_Byte_{}.txt".format(b)
    test = read_list(path)
    print(test)
    print(type(test)) # check we have a list not a string
```

Comment: It gives me this error:     data = ast.literal_eval(raw_data)
NameError: global name 'ast' is not defined

Comment: You of course need to import the ast module, sorry I thought this was obvious enough ;-)

Comment: Added the `ast` import to the snippet.

Comment: @pitty_san it works __with the example you gave__. Instead of complaining with a totally useless description of your problem ("doesn't work" will not help) you may want to clarify your question, provide meaningful inputs and expected outputs samples, and cleary explain _how_ it "doesn't work" instead.